# UIActionSheet buttons to display view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiactionsheet

I am trying to make the buttons in my UIActionSheet perform a view change using the following code.

```
-(void)displayActionSheet:(id)sender
    {

actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:nil
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Devanagari", @"English", nil];

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

[actionSheet showInView:self.view ];

[actionSheet release];

}
```

How can I modify this code to make the Devanagari, and English buttons link to their own separate views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the sake of making this less confusing, you may want to consider naming your actionSheet something other than actionSheet.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(actionSheet == actionSheet)
        {

switch (buttonIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                {
            DevanagariViewController *controller1 = [[DevanagariViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DevanagariViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:NO];
                NSLog(@"DevanagariViewController");
                break;
                }


                case 1:
                {
                            EnglishViewController *controller2 = [[EnglishViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EnglishViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:controller2 animated:NO];
                NSLog(@"EnglishViewController");
                break;
                }


            }   


        }
```

Comment: Not only less confusing, `actionSheet == actionSheet` always evaluates as `true`. You should probably change the parameter name, or use `self->actionSheet` or make it a property and use `self.actionSheet`

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Devanagari"]) {
        //Code if Devanagari button is pressed
    }
    if([title isEqualToString:@"English"]) {
        //Code if English button is pressed
    }
}
```